# Detect sudden scroll stop in UIScrollView

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uiscrollviewdelegate

I would like to know how to use the `UIScrollViewDelegate` to detect when the scroll view stops moving suddenly because the user has touched and held the screen after momentum  has been initiated from a fast pan.

The `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:` method only fires for the above case when the user has lifted their finger. However, if the user taps and holds during scroll view momentum then this method doesn't fire (until they lift their finger). Is there anyways to intercept this when the scroll view stops dead upon the user's touch down?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you could have a flag that is raised when the user *starts* scrolling, which ends in `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating`.  That way, if the user starts scrolling again before the flag is cleared, you will know that they touched it during a deceleration.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried using `scrollViewWillBeginDragging`? Alternatively (since the docs indicate that `scrollViewWillBeginDragging` may not fire immediately) you can try using `scrollViewDidScroll` and checking if the user is currently touching the scrollview...

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    if(scrollView.isTracking){
        //do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to implement your own.

Our friend Apple already provides you the way to detect the situation.

if needed for more, reference guide here : https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollviewdelegate/1619436-scrollviewdidenddragging

```
func scrollViewDidEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, willDecelerate decelerate: Bool) {
    if decelerate {
      print("true if scrolling stops, keeping touch on the screen!")
    } else {
      print("false if scrolling stops, detaching touch on the screen")
    }
}
```